# Time we attended to [time-and-attendance]

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

[time-and-attendance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/time-and-attendance) (6 watchers, 115 questions) has a fully-developed tag wiki, but it includes an over-broad (IMO) statement that:

> Also appropriate are generalized questions that would be useful if building an in-house Time and Attendance system.

The overall feel of the tag info seems quite meta to me, and looking at the questions they seem to be either over-broad "Gimmie teh codez/skeemaz" or are quite detailed and gain nothing from the tag.

1. **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied?** and **is it unambiguous?**

   As the tag's wiki-excerpt says, "keep[ing] track of people's comings and goings" is off-topic on Stack Overflow, and there are five bullet points listing concrete problems within this tag's scope that could be more appropriate tags, so I'd say it is quite ambiguous.
2. **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

   Generalised questions about T&A alone might be better in [Database Adminstrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com).
3. **Does the tag add *any* meaningful information to the post?**

   No. Looking at the tagged questions this tag perhaps even hides meaningful information, as the real problem is with SQL, or Java, or hardware integration.
4. **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

   Well, I suppose it does, but as pointed out in Q1, it's a far too woolly and meta concept to be useful.

So, in summary, I think a lot of the current questions under this tag should be re-tagged to describe the actual issue that is the problem.